# Odd Profiler Trace Replay Error

Tags: sql-server-2016, sql-server-2005

I am working on migrating a client from a really old SQL Server 2005 database server to a SQL Server 2016 install. Everything appears to be fine for database import, validation, testing...etc. I've even shifted one of their applications over to the new server for testing, all is good. I decided to capture about 30 minutes of trace data from their current 2005 install using the 'replay' template in the SQL Profiler. I then replayed this trace data on the SQL Server 2016 install. The results seem fine except for a single error that keeps popping up in the replay trace data:

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]
Invalid object name 'xxxx'. (State 42S02) (Code 208)
```

With xxxx being the name of table. When I check the query that produces this message and run it, it works fine. I know from testing the application (where these queries occur) that it's working fine. The application is using ODBC.
Am I missing something here or can these errors be ignored? If they can, what is causing them?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e667385a-482c-4973-b390-bf6d4eda6228/profiler-bug-invalid-object-name-results?forum=transactsql

Comment: Interesting, that does seem consistent with the message I keep seeing. That is likely the issue, but I'll leave the question open still for a more complete answer from others, for future reference to people with a similar issue.